# TextView under two list views

Tags: android, android-layout

I've tried various solutions asked here on stackoverflow for the same problem but nothing is working for me. I want to display two text views under two list views. My code is this

```
<LinearLayout
....>
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv1InBS"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv2InBS"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#800000"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#800000"
            android:typeface="serif" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

....

Please help. I've been sick trying to correct it.
Thanks.

Comment: Please explain exactly how do you want it to look like

Comment: I want my two textviews fixed while I can scroll through my listviews

Comment: Basically there's some kind of total in those text views. So, I want that the user can scroll through the various transactions while total always appears on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

ok you should try this methodology,

first take a simple linear layout with vertical orientation,
than add two list view and two text views in the way you want it on the screen,
than go to grafical editor and select first component, either listview or text view than click on the distribute waight evenly button given on the upper panel of the graphical editor.

This will work for sure.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/welcome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/welcome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/welcome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

add this in your xml and have a look,because it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , here is a way to do it, by combining the **Weight** attribute of android views and **Horizontal/Vertical LinearLayouts**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

- The first Horizontal Linearlayout acts as a container for the two parallel rows.
- inside each row there are two vertical layouts ( by using equal weights and *layout_width="0"*) the layouts would split the screen in half.
- Inside each LinearLayout a listView item (with height set to zero and weight to 1) and a textview item with any values you want.